# How to use the initialized Webdriver instance from Base class to child class java

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

```
public class Base 
{
    public WebDriver driver;

    @BeforeMethod 
    public void setUp()
    {
        driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    }

}

public class useFunction extends Base
{

    public useFunction(WebDriver driver)
    {
        this.driver = driver;
    }

    public void func1()
    {
        driver.findElement().click();  //driver is null
        --------
        ---------
    }
}

Public class Test extends Base
{
    useFunction funObj = new useFunction(driver);
    @Test
    public void testMethod1()
   {
       funObj.func1();
       ----
       ------ 

  }
}
```

**How can i use the initialized value of WebDriver instance in `UseFunction class` without declaring the Webdriver instance as static.** When i pass the driver in constructor of `UseFunction class` while creating its object inside `Test class`, getting Null Pointer Exception

Comment: Can you please explain why won't use your driver as static?

Answer (score 0):

Initialize web driver in base class constructor and extend Base class in Test class then assign driver to Base.driver.

Try below code

**Base Class:**

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class Base 
{
public WebDriver driver;

public Base(){
    driver = new ChromeDriver();
}
}
```

**UseFunction class:**

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;

public class useFunction
 {
     WebDriver driver;

  public useFunction(WebDriver driver)
  {
    this.driver = driver;
  }

  public void func1()
  {
    driver.findElement(By.id("id of the element")).click(); 
  }
  }
```

**Test1 class:**

```
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class Test1{

@Test
public void testMethod1()
{
    Base base = new Base();
    useFunction funObj = new useFunction(base.driver);
    funObj.func1(); 

}
}
```

Try it and let me know if it works for you

Comment: I need to initialize it without declaring it as **Static** . Thanks

Comment: Updated my answer by removing static keyword of driver object, please verify and let me know if you have any queries

Comment: -Thanks.It work in this way but is it good practice to write the whole logic for initializing the webdriver instance inside constructor of Base class . How can i use annotation or if i need to perform some more action after initializing the driver.

Answer (score 0):

```
public WebDriver Base() {

  WebDriverManager.edgedriver().setup(); //Change for Chrome.

    EdgeOptions options = new EdgeOptions();
    options.addArguments("--remote-allow-origins=*");

    WebDriver ed = new EdgeDriver(options);
    ed.manage().window().maximize();
    ed.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(Duration.ofSeconds(30));

    return ed;
}
```

Test1:

```
public class Test1 extends Base {

    public void Test1_TestNG() throws InterruptedException {

        WebDriver ed = Base();
        ed.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(Duration.ofSeconds(30));
    }   
}
```

Now you can use "ed" WebDriver for any methods (OR) further Web Based automation, by simply calling "ed" WebDriver.